# Should I use a ListView for single-row data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I use Asp.net 4 and C#.

I'm developing a simple CMS, at the moment I want to displays the content for a specific PAGE (Title, BodyContent, and some other fields) at the end user on a web page (like as this website display its questions to its Users).

I need wrap my fields from database in appropriate HTML TAGS example `<h1>Title</h1>` `<div>BodyContent</div>`.

The resulting page should be READ ONLY .

I would like to know:

1. If a ListView web control with setting for a single row would be the
   right choice (maybe binded with ObjectDataSource).
2. If would be better use separate Web Controls like Literals or
   Labels to displays my fields sparsely on my webpage
3. In case of previous point how would I DataBind every single Control? Using different DataBinder or maybe with Linq an projecting using Anonymous Type.

I'm mainly concerned with read-only performance.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones :-)

Comment: thanks zod, but I think is not a clone my question

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with Stack Overflow itself. You don't need that in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have data that's a single row, there's not much point in using a ListView. They're designed for showing *lists* of data (hence the name). If you have one item, consider either a DetailsView or single Labels.

If you have a particular class that often needs to be displayed in a certain way, consider setting up a Web User Control that can be bound to instances of that class.

Comment: Thanks Justin, if I use different Labels, and I use different Linq queries to populate this labels... what about use of memory for this separates queries? Wont be better materialize all fields using a single Data Source control? Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: @GibboK - If you're talking about performance, it just depends on your implementation. I wouldn't be too concerned as long as your LINQ queries are planned out in an intelligent way (i.e. try to minimize database roundtrips, avoid duplication of data or logic, etc.). As long as you're pulling the same data from the DB, there shouldn't be much difference between using several data structures and using one.